# NServiceBus Host that Subscribes to his own Published Messages

Tags: nservicebus, publish-subscribe, database-deadlocks

Used Version of NServiceBus: 2.0.0.1145

### Question:

Is it possible to configure a NServiceBus Host in such a way that, it consumes (subcribes to) his own published messages?

### Answer:

It seems possible, but in the following Configuration it gives me a Transaction deadlocked Exception while trying to insert Subscriptions into the SubscriptionStorage.
It happens when you use DbSubscriptionStorage and more than 1 "NumberOfWorkerThreads".

### Error:

`Could not execute command:

INSERT INTO Subscription (SubscriberEndpoint, MessageType) VALUES (@p0, @p1)

System.Data.SqlClinet.SqlException:

Transaction was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.`

After that NServiceBus tries to disconnect but fails because there is a transaction still in progress and throws an UnhandledException.

## How to reproduce:

#### Here is my App.Config:

```
<!-- Publishing Configuration -->
<MsmqTransportConfig InputQueue="test_publisher_output" ErrorQueue="test_error" NumberOfWorkerThreads="3" MaxRetries="5" />

<!-- Subscription Configuration -->
<UnicastBusConfig DistributorControlAddress="" DistributorDataAddress="" ForwardReceivedMessagesTo="">
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
        <add Messages="MessageAssembly" Endpoint="test_publisher_output" />
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
</UnicastBusConfig>
```

#### My Bus-Configuration:

```
var bus = Configure.With()
    .Log4Net()
    .StructureMapBuilder(container)
    .XmlSerializer()
    .MsmqTransport()
        .IsTransactional(true)
        .PurgeOnStartup(false)
    .DBSubcriptionStorage(subscriptionDbProperties, true)
    .Sagas()
    .NHibernateSagaPersister(sagaDbProperties, true)
    .UnicastBus()
        .ImpersonateSender(false)
        .LoadMessageHandlers(First<GridInterceptingMessageHandler>
            .Then<SagaMessageHandler>())
    .CreateBus()
    .Start();
```

and here are my dbProperties for both the subscription and the saga db:

```
connection.provider      NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider
connection.driver_class  NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver
dialect                  NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect
```

Everything works fine as long as i don't increase the NumberOfWorkerThreads above 1. Everything higher than that and it will throw the above stated errors.

I hope i haven't forgotten anything. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Why would the same endpoint want to subscribe to messages that it is publishing itself? I mean, if you wanted to have additional things happen in the same endpoint, you could just put them in the code that did the publish in the first place.

Comment: Hi Udi, because i would then loose on the stability nservicebus gives me. i want to breakdown a whole bunch of work into small packages that are executed by messagehandlers. examples of work done here are calling webservices, opening ftp connections, creating and converting xml-files, databasetransactions etc.. also i would like to have the option to just publish or send a message and don't want to care about the endpoint. the administrators of the application should decide where to host endpoints. in the simplest configuration this whole bunch of work should be done in one host.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would really consider a re-design of this component.  If you want the stability nservicebus gives you, and you've already broken the component down so each part of the processing is in a separate message handler, put each message handler in a separate executable with a separate queue.  If that isn't possible, well then you haven't really got the stability of nservicebus as you are locked down by some other pieces of code in which case you should just directly call the required functions.

If you are just testing them all running off one queue, then just split them up when you test as well.  There really is no reason to subscribe to your own messages - either split the handlers into seperate endpoints if possible, and if not possible then call the functions directly.

Comment: as surprisingly as this insight was to me, this seems to be the correct answer. split your services. have nservicebus only on the outside boundaries of your service. understand the usages of send, publish, reply. my questioned implementation of above is not supported (by design) with nservicebus.

Comment: Why not? If my executable has one part that takes a long time to process, why not have that part started by a command and result in a saga completing it?  NServiceBus would determine that the handling server1 with my exe1 which originally sent the message (to itself) is now busy, and a different server with my same exe1 would now handle it correctly! No?  Isn't that what should happen if two of the same commands were received from an extrenal client, and my server running exe1 is bogged down. Doesn't NServiceBus handle this automatically and send it to server2 running exe1?

Comment: This seems to contradict the CQRS model. Your query side (in the same process) would have event handlers that would forward that message on to denormalizers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the same process to handle a published message it would be better to do a Bus.SendLocal() after Bus.Publish().  The SendLocal() method will place a message on the local queue and your internal handler will pick it up and process it.  This will get rid of your deadlock yet keep the same semantics.

Comment: Hi Adam, no the problem is the subscription not the send or publish of a message. so the problem already occurs while starting up the host where no messages are sent or published.